# Postgraphile: Only some parameters in a function required

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

When I write a function in Postgresql I can add strict resulting in all parameters being required in Graphql (!), without strict all parameters are optional.

On required fields in the non strict function I can throw exceptions or simply return null without executing the function like the strict function would do when the parameter is null. But how can I tell Postgraphile which parameters are required? Via a comment or something, or marking parameters which have a default as optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my search I found this question asked [here](https://github.com/graphile/postgraphile/issues/438), and especially [this](https://github.com/graphile/postgraphile/issues/438#issuecomment-322134305) answer.
The answer I found in quote:

> This functionality is implemented in graphile-build-pg via the
>   pgStrictFunctions setting, but this isn't currently exposed via
>   postgraphile-core to PostGraphQL itself. What it does is treats all
>   functions as strict, requiring all arguments to be marked as required
>   unless they have defaults.
>
> It is possible to mark an argument as default null, but of course a
>   strict function with a null default will automatically return null
>   without being called.

```
create function a(b int, c int default null)
returns int as $$
  select b;
$$ language sql stable;
```

> By default neither b nor c will be required, but with
>   pgStrictFunctions set b will be marked as required (but c will not).

While it mentions a solution it does not state how to implement it. Searching the entire project (including node_modules) for 'pgStrictFunctions' did not give any clues either. How to implement I finally found on discord, this is how I finally got it working:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [],
  imports: [
    PostGraphileModule.forRoot({
      ......
      graphileBuildOptions: {
        pgStrictFunctions: true,
      },
      ......
    }),
  ],
  providers: [GraphQLService],
})
```

Comment: Indeed, this is not an official feature currently (though it has worked for a long time and I don't intend to break it). In PostGraphile v5 I will probably enable it by default. Thanks for helping to document it.

Comment: @Benjie What about making it as a configuration option?

Comment: It is a configuration option? `pgStrictFunctions` under `graphileBuildOptions`.